# Can't find the right index for the missing date

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to generate missing values from missing dates in an obj array structure,
In below code I generate the missing values, but the dates are incorrect, can anyone point me towards a solution where I with the given index can generate the correct date from the preceding value

```js
const obj= {
    arr: [ 
        { num: 1, date: new Date("2020-11-13T16:23:57.460Z") },
        { num: 2, date: new Date("2020-11-14T20:19:42.186Z") },
        { num: 3, date: new Date("2020-11-15T14:58:09.203Z") },
        { num: 4, date: new Date("2020-11-16T18:55:38.491Z") },
        // { num: 5, date: new Date("2020-11-17T23:40:55.084Z") },
        // { num: 6, date: new Date("2020-11-18T03:44:49.573Z") },
        // { num: 7, date: new Date("2020-11-19T03:44:49.573Z") },
        { num: 8, date: new Date("2020-11-20T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
        { num: 9, date: new Date("2020-11-21T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
        { num: 10, date: new Date("2020-11-22T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
        { num: 11, date: new Date("2020-11-23T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
    ]
}
function ensure_time_line(source) {
  for (let index in source.timeline) {
    let i = parseInt(index)
    let src = get_item(source.timeline, i)
    let next = get_item(source.timeline, i + 1)
    let current_date = new Date(src.date);
    current_date.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    // console.log('rc',src)
    if (next) {
      // console.log(next)
      let tomorrow = new Date(current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 1));
      let next_date = new Date(next.date);
      next_date.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
      console.log(next_date, tomorrow, src.date)
      if (tomorrow.getTime() === next_date.getTime()) {
        continue;
      }
      let q = source.timeline.splice(i + 1, 0, {
        num: src.num,
        date: tomorrow
      })
    }
  }
}
```

outputs

```
[ { num: 1, date: 2020-11-13T16:23:57.460Z },
  { num: 2, date: 2020-11-14T20:19:42.186Z },
  { num: 3, date: 2020-11-15T14:58:09.203Z },
  { num: 4, date: 2020-11-16T18:55:38.491Z },
  { num: 5, date: 2020-11-17T23:40:55.084Z },
  { num: 5, date: 2020-11-17T23:40:55.084Z },
  { num: 5, date: 2020-11-17T23:40:55.084Z },
  { num: 5, date: 2020-11-17T23:40:55.084Z },
  { num: 5, date: 2020-11-17T23:40:55.084Z },
  { num: 9, date: 2020-11-21T03:44:49.573Z },
  { num: 10, date: 2020-11-22T03:44:49.573Z },
  { num: 11, date: 2020-11-23T03:44:49.573Z } ]
```

Comment: is the expected output really `num:5` multiple times?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes that is really the desired output if aboove was the usecase

Answer (score 1):

There are several pieces of information that are not given, like how the time of the day changes, but here is a demo snippet:

```js
const obj= {
    timeline: [ 
        { num: 1, date: new Date("2020-11-13T16:23:57.460Z") },
        { num: 2, date: new Date("2020-11-14T20:19:42.186Z") },
        { num: 3, date: new Date("2020-11-15T14:58:09.203Z") },
        { num: 4, date: new Date("2020-11-16T18:55:38.491Z") },
        // { num: 5, date: new Date("2020-11-17T23:40:55.084Z") },
        // { num: 6, date: new Date("2020-11-18T03:44:49.573Z") },
        // { num: 7, date: new Date("2020-11-19T03:44:49.573Z") },
        { num: 8, date: new Date("2020-11-20T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
        { num: 9, date: new Date("2020-11-21T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
        { num: 10, date: new Date("2020-11-22T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
        { num: 11, date: new Date("2020-11-23T03:44:49.573Z") }, 
    ]
};


function ensure_time_line(source) {
  let result = {timeline: []};
  let src;
  let next;
  for (let i = 0; i < (source.timeline.length - 1); i++) {
    src = source.timeline[i];
    next = source.timeline[i + 1];
    let current_date = src.date;
    //console.log('rc',src)
    if (next) {
      // console.log(next)
      let tomorrow = new Date();
      tomorrow.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 1);
      result.timeline.push(src);
      while (tomorrow.toDateString() !== next.date.toDateString()) {
        src = {
          num: src.num + 1,
          date: new Date(tomorrow)
        };
        result.timeline.push(src);
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(ensure_time_line(obj));
```

Since the time of day changes from element 4 to element 8, I have used `toDateString()` to compare dates.